# How to manage multiple file changes/deletes/add in git (Drupal)

Tags: git, drupal

I keep running into the situation with git where I am working on a Drupal project where I need to switch a module (Views Auto-Refresh for Block Refresh.)  This change involves removing a folder full of files and replacing it with another folder full of files.  It also my involve the creation / deletion of various files in other places.  My fear is that git won't process the change correctly (because I am not removing the files correctly.)  How do I correctly handle project changes where several files are added, removed, or have their name changed?

Although I want to remove these files from the current state of the git repo, I still want them to exist in older states (I don't want to completely remove them from the repo.)

Answer (score 0):

### Adding several files:

`git add newfiles/` (if they are in one folder) *or*
`git add newfile1 newfile2 path/to/newfile3` otherwise

### Removing several files:

`git rm -r oldfiles/` (if you want to remove a complete folder) *or*
`git rm oldfile1 oldfile2 path/to/oldfile3` otherwise

### Renaming files:

`git mv old new` (you need to do every file / folder on its own here).

None of these commands change the "history" in git (this is not possible without a rebase, which is rather complicated).
When you are done you need to commit (`git commit`) the changes.

I suggest you read an introduction to git before continuing working with it, try http://git-scm.com/book or http://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1 (the second is interactive, give it a shot!)